# Can a fourth-order equation be solved like a quadratic equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

I was asked to find the zeros of  $y = x^4 + 5x^2 +6$.

I tried to turn this into a quadratic to factor it as follows:

$y = x^4 + 5x^2 +6 = {(x^2)}^2 + 5{(x^2)}^1 + 6$

Put another way:

Let $t = {x^2}$

$y = t^2 + 5t +6$

$y = (t + 6)(t - 1)$

$t =$ {$-6, 1$}

I threw out the -6 solution, but thought that if $t = x^2 = 1$, then $x = 1$.

I can see that when I plug 1 back into the original formula, $1^4 + 5(1^2) + 6 \ne 0$, but I don't know where I went wrong conceptually.

Comment: $y = (t+2)(t+3)$

Comment: How embarrassing. So does that mean $\sqrt{-2}$ and $\sqrt{-3}$ *are* solutions? And the reason it says "no zeros" is because solutions with imaginary numbers are not zeros? I'm still unclear if this is an OK approach and I just can't add/multiply.

Comment: The roots are $i \sqrt 2, -i \sqrt 2, i \sqrt 3, -i \sqrt 3.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do what you are trying.  The only problem is you did not factor it correctly, as the constant term would be $-6$ instead of $+6$

Answer (score 2):

You factored incorrectly. It factors into $y = (t+2)(t+3)$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is a valid method. In reply to your comment about the answer being "no zeros," that comes from the fact that there are no *real* zeros, which is what that means.

If you were looking for only real roots, you could have also deduced that from looking at the original equation. $x^4$ and $x^2$ are always positive, thus for real $x,  x^4 + 5x^2 + 6 > 0$